# regular expression allow the user to give few spcl char?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am givng a regular expression validation to a text box, which is not allowing the using to enter spcl. char. its allowing the user to enter only numbers or char.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">
            </asp:TextBox><asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$"
                    ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox2"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I want to allow the user to give few spcl char like apostrophe ' ampersand & and hyphen - with numbers and char. means if the user wants to use these three spcl. then he/she can use, is this possible if yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is very possible. Just include the characters in your expression.

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z\&\'\- ]+$
```